# Successor with Finish-to-start relationship starts at the same time as predecessor

Tags: ms-project

When adding a task with a relationship Finish-to-Start, successor task starts at the same time as predecessor task. I have tried moving the task by dragging the second task, but then another problem (with dotted lines) came in. Here is how it looks like right now:

[image]

What I would ideally like is to have all (non-summary) tasks in a sequential order, e.g. task2 starts when task1 finishes, task3 starts when task2 finishes, etc.

Any ideas how to achieve that tasks start after one another and recalculate dates automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check marks indicate you have actual data loaded into this schedule.  Therefore, the two tasks you want to schedule in sequence are showing as starting the same time because you have an actual start date loaded into the successor task that must be the same as its predecessor.  Actual data will override scheduled or planned data.

Build a new schedule from scratch.

Comment: I'd suggest you also use auto scheduled tasks - not manually scheduled.  You can select all tasks in the project, and click 0% complete on the Task Ribbon to remove all the actuals.